# Does the projectile motion equation work if the initial height and final heights are different?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, kinematics, projectile

Hi just a quick question here.[image]

Does this equation work if the initial height and final height for the projectile is different? Suppose you throw a ball off a cliff and you want to find the vertical displacement of the ball when it is below the initial height.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes. Substitute y with $\Delta y$!